# Saving attachments from Mail.app through ScriptingBridge (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to retrieve attachments from Mail.app through scriptingbridge. I'm using the following code to get access to my inbox messages.

```
MailApplication *mailApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.mail"];
MailMailbox *inbox = [mailApp inbox];
SBElementArray *messages = [inbox messages];
```

By iterating over the `SBElementArray`, I can access an individual `MailMessage` object.

Each `MailMessage` object has a getter that retrieves another `SBElementArray`, this time filled with `MailMailAttachment` objects.

It's working, because if I put a `NSLog(@"count:%lu",mailitem.attachments.count);` it will print the correct amount of attachments. File name and size are also correct printed.

But when I iterate over the attachments array and save it, nothing happens.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL new] initFileURLWithPath:@"/Users/usr/Documents/tmp/"];
NSLog(@"count:%lu",mailitem.attachments.count);
for (MailMailAttachment *attachment in mailitem.attachments) {
   NSLog(@"name:%@",attachment.name);
   NSLog(@"size:%ld",attachment.fileSize);
   [attachment saveIn:url as:MailSaveableFileFormatNativeFormat];
}
```

I didn't found any documentation about this method. From header file, it says:

```
- (void) saveIn:(NSURL *)in_ as:(MailSaveableFileFormat)as;  // Save a document.
```

I'm assuming that the NSURL is the place in which I want to store the file, but I have no idea about `MailSaveableFileFormat`. I'm passing `MailSaveableFileFormatNativeFormat`, that I found on header file, but as I said, nothing happens. Not even a simple error message.

I also tried to initialize the NSURL with a directory and a complete filepath (path + filename). Same result.

Does anyone has an example? How do I save it?

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I was initializing NSURL wrong... The code that worked is:

```
for (MailMailAttachment *attachment in mailitem.attachments) {
   NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"/Users/usr/Documents/tmp/",attachment.name];
   NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
   [attachment saveIn:fileUrl as:MailSaveableFileFormatNativeFormat];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my old system, I use a file path and nil like this `[attachment saveIn:file_Path as:nil];`

In my "Mail.h" : `saveIn:(NSString *)in_ as:(NSString *)as;`.

I know it changed on Lion **NSURL** instead of **NSString**) , but not in AppleScript script, you must specify the file path without suffering any other parameter --> `save thisAttachment in filePath -- Applescript`

So I think the complete **file path + as:nil** should work.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't worked. I figured out that I was initializing NSURL wrong... By the way, in my Mail.h, it has that MailSaveableFileFormatNativeFormat = 'item' /* Native format */